# Problemas ao rodar o servidor rails com vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant

Criei uma box Xenial Xerus 64x com o vagrant, instalei o rvm com rails.

Estou rodando o servidor na VM tranquilo, consigo acessar lá pela VM o servidor rails rodando, mas não consigo acessar do meu browser local.

Já tinha usado o vagrant outras vezes mas sempre conseguia subir a aplicação usando rails s -b 0.0.0.0 e no meu browser local abro o localhost:3000.

Mas nessa VM que criei não está funcionando.

Answer (score -1):

Rafael,

Já configurou as portas no Vagrantfile?

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
```